# Angular 2 Array printed on console but can't print object property on screen

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have the following method in a service I've created:

```
  getPost(nid: string): Observable<Post[]>{
    let url = "http://test.co.uk/api/v1/basic/" + nid;
    return this.http.get(url,  {headers: this.headers}).map(res => res.json() as Post).catch(err => {

      return Observable.throw(err);
    });
  }
```

And this is the class of my component:

```
export class PostDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  posts: Post[] = [];
  post: Post = new Post();
  constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private postService: PostService
) { }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.switchMap((params: Params) => {
      let nid = params ['nid'];
      return this.postService.getPost(nid);  }).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.post = res as Post;
    }, err =>{
      console.log(err);
  });

  }

}
```

The JSON feed looks like this(yes one object in the array):

```
  [  
   {  
      "nid":"3",
      "title":"When Unity meets Vuforia",
      "body":"<p>Unless you have been living under a rock in the past 7 - ...",
      "uid":"admin",
      "path":"\/node\/3",
      "field_article_image":"http:\/\/test.co.uk\/sites\/default\/files\/when-unity-meets-vuforia_0.jpg?itok=BGYaotay"
   }
]
```

So in my template, if I print `{{post}}` I get [object Object] on the screen.

If I print `{{post | json}}` I get the row JSON feed.

And finally, if I print `{{post.title}}` or `{{post?.title}}` I don't get anything.

I also have a class Post that is looking like this:

```
export class Post{
  constructor(

public nid?: string,
public title?: string,
public body?: string
public image?: string
  ){
  }
}
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning an array into what should be a single object. Copy the first element of the array into the post variable

```
this.post = res[0] as Post
```

Side note:  It's incorrect to assign a raw object to a class instance. In this case, your `this.post.constructor` won't exist and `this.post instanceof Post == false`.

You could do `Object.assign(this.post, res[0])` but you may need to clear existing properties if not all properties are always present.

I prefer to define object shapes as interfaces instead, then you would not have that problem because all the interface information is removed at runtime, whereas a class does emit some code instead of just doing static type checks at compilation time

Comment: That was what I needed...thank you, Juan. Would be nice if you can point me to an place where I can read more about this.

Comment: Read more about what? Assigning an array where an object is expected and masking the error because you cast it? Not sure what part is unclear